# Why does the error occur even though the containers have other ports exposed?

Tags: kubernetes

I am just started learning K8S and can't understand the following behaviour.
There are two web servers in one pod - httpd and nginx and they have different ports exposed. For this reason, they should not disturb each other and serve their contents without issues.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: error
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - containerPort: 81
  - name: http
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - containerPort: 82
```

Nevertheless an error occurs. Only one, first (nginx) container starts and prevent the other to start as well.

```bash
user@lenovo:~/kubernetes$ k get po
NAME    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS     AGE
error   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   1 (5s ago)   12s
```

```bash
user@lenovo:~/kubernetes$ k get po
NAME    READY   STATUS   RESTARTS      AGE
error   1/2     Error    3 (43s ago)   67s
```

```bash
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m25s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/error to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    5m25s                  kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal   Pulled     5m23s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 1.389459751s (1.389484948s including waiting)
  Normal   Created    5m23s                  kubelet            Created container nginx
  Normal   Started    5m23s                  kubelet            Started container nginx
  Normal   Pulled     5m22s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "httpd" in 1.302154906s (1.302180721s including waiting)
  Normal   Pulled     5m19s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "httpd" in 1.295687346s (1.295734944s including waiting)
  Normal   Pulled     5m3s                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "httpd" in 1.351543448s (1.351557664s including waiting)
  Normal   Pulling    4m36s (x4 over 5m23s)  kubelet            Pulling image "httpd"
  Normal   Pulled     4m35s                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "httpd" in 1.347083725s (1.347108033s including waiting)
  Normal   Created    4m34s (x4 over 5m22s)  kubelet            Created container http
  Normal   Started    4m34s (x4 over 5m21s)  kubelet            Started container http
  Warning  BackOff    12s (x25 over 5m18s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container http in pod error_default(5c50ccec-f5a3-402f-962f-c7a15349092e)
```

I would gladly know the reason behind that behaviour. I haven't found the answer in the net, checked logs, got info from kubectl describe pod, etc.

I tried to find the answer in the net and here on StackOverflow, checked logs, got info from kubectl describe pod, etc.

Just noticed:

```bash
user@lenovo:~/kubernetes$ k logs error -c http
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.244.0.56. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting a `containerPort:` value at the Kubernetes level doesn't change the containers' behavior at all.  Both the Nginx and Apache HTTPD servers by default listen on the standard HTTP port 80, but since you've launched them in the same Pod, they share a network namespace, and there's a conflict.

In principle you can avoid this problem by reconfiguring one server or the other to use a different port.  You need to modify the server configuration, for example getting an `nginx.conf` from a ConfigMap and mounting that into the Nginx container.

In practice, though, you should avoid running multiple things in the same Pod, and you should generally avoid running Pods directly.  I'd break this into two Deployments

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
```

An Apache HTTPD Deployment would look similar.  At the end, note that the `containerPort:` matches what the server process inside the Pod is using, and also that we've given it a `name:`.

The port number on a Pod doesn't "really" matter, since you'll almost always access it via a Service.  The Service can refer to the name of the port.  Regardless of what the application is doing, I'd recommend setting the Service to always listen on the normal port for its protocol.  (So an HTTP Service would listen on port 80, even if a Flask application internally uses port 5000 while an Express application would use port 3000 by default.)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx          # Deployment spec.template.metadata.labels
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80          # standard HTTP port
      targetPort: http  # port name from Pod spec
```

Comment: David, thank you very much for answering my question! I'm really excited to learn a little more. Honestly, I can't grasp the concept of Deployments because I haven't learned about them yet. I understand that: 1) as a rule of thumb we do not create containers both serving something on the same ports in the same pod eg. two web servers 2) we might prepare/change the configuration e.g. /etc/nginx/nginx.conf - to serve content on a different port, but this does not make much sense because we can simplify the case by using Deployments.

Comment: In general, you should avoid creating more than one container in a Pod, and you should avoid directly creating Pods, instead preferring single-container Deployments (or Jobs or StatefulSets).  The Service is the piece that lets you remap the port for other consumers.